# Most efficient way to store resources

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have a very long list of names, say a few hundred, and possibly some other information attached to those names. I want to use this data in the program, but also want to store it externally.

What external storage method would be the fastest to load the data into the program during compile time. I.E, should I store the data in a text file (using my own sort of syntax), another .cpp file, a library, or some other file type? And what would be the best way to import such data?

Comment: Please consider define how big is big.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a file and then instead of opening and reading it runtime, you could use the file compile(or, rather, pre-compile-)-time, like so

```
// names.txt
"Jack",
"Jill",
"Matt",
...
"Harry"
```

In your cpp file:

```
std::vector<std::string> names = {
#include "names.txt"
};
```

Remember that `#include` simply copy-pastes the contents of the including file.